# ImageListView - Thumbnails not displaying

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I have added the imagelistview to a usercontrol with a button. The imagelistview is a customized external that is available on nuget (found at the link http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageListView/). I am running .net 4.0 and coding in vb.net

I have set the imagelistview cache mode to continuous and placed the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ImageListView1.SetRenderer(New Manina.Windows.Forms.ImageListViewRenderers.TilesRenderer(200))

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = vbOK Then

        Dim file As String

        For Each file In OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileNames

            ImageListView1.Items.Add(file)

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

However the images are not displaying their thumbnail. How do you display the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question

The reason why the thumbnails were not loading, is that I was using the SafeFileNames property instead of using the FileNames property.

Since the string only ever contained the file name only,the images were never added to the ImageListView control. Only the image file type icon and the file name were added.

When adding images to the ImageListView the string must contain the full file address (folder directory and file name).

If the imagelistview cannot find the image it will display its file type icon as the thumbnail.